# Why can't I perform a segue while write data to my Firebase database?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, segue

I am trying to perform a segue from one view controller to another so that I can pass data. I am passing text from a text field to a label. Also, I am trying to write data from that text field to my Firebase database. It will not allow me to write the data the same time as I perform a segue. Why is this and how can I do both at the same time?

I have created a show segue between two view controllers with the identifier "nextTransition". The segue work when I press the button before adding in the database code. Once I add in the code to write into my database, I have the issue where I cannot write to it. It tried to perform the segue using a func but it did not change anything.

```
@IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: Any) {
ref?.child("Title").childByAutoId().setValue("titleTextField.text")

performNextTransitionSegue()
```

Below this is the function I created for the show segue "nextTransition".

```
func performNextTransitionSegue() {
    if titleTextField.text != "" {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "nextTransition", sender: self)
    }
}
```

I expected it to create display the titleTextField.text in the Firebase database but instead it didn't do anything.

Comment: I believe writing to firebase is an async function. Maybe when you segue to a new VC, it closes the connection to firebase before it is done writing. Try segueing in the completion handler of the setValue?  _ref.setValue(object) { (error, ref) -> Void in

}_

Comment: I posted an answer to complete the code which you mentioned in your comment, if you would like to add it as an answer I can delete mine @Mocha

Answer (score 1):

Writing to firebase is an async function. When you segue to a new VC, it closes the connection to firebase before it is done writing. Segue to your new VC in the completion handler of the setValue method.

```
ref?.child("Title").childByAutoId().setValue(`YourValue`) { (error, ref) in
        if error == nil {
            self.performNextTransitionSegue()
        } else {
            print("error")
        }
    }
```

Comment: @emrepun Thank you for allowing me credit. I wasn't 100% sure if this was the answer.

Comment: I am a little confused about the .setValue(locationObject). I get an error when I use that in my code. The error displays, "Use of unresolved identifier 'locationObject'; did you mean '_nativeObject'?" Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: @MikeD. locationObject is whatever value you want it to be... e.g. "TestValue" - See updated answer

Answer (score 1):

As I see, you have a mistake in this line:

```
ref?.child("Title").childByAutoId().setValue("titleTextField.text")
```

Because the

> titleTextField.text

Must not be a String I mean it doesn't need to be in quotation marks.

After that please check that

```
titleTextField.text != ""
```

is getting some value this probably avoid you to go through the segue, you can check it with debugger.

And if the line is running check if your segue is named correctly.